# Printing problems with HTML

Tags: html

I have a page that returns a formatted data dump of about three hundred pages when printed.  The problem is that between pages it often puts half of one line on the first page and the bottom half of the line on a second page.

I don't want to force a new page for every record.  I just want a complete line to appear on each page, not split between the two pages.  Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should check out the W3C's page about [Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html), especially the part on `page-break-inside`.